# Module returns different result from the script version [Test-Path]

Tags: powershell, module

## introduction

I've written my first PowerShell script aimed for retrieving detailed information from a Windows Setup ISO file. Once the basic features achieved, I've started to convert the **ps1** script into a **psm1** module. I hoped the result would be the module just work like the script but I'm facing issue I'm not able to solve.

You can download my work [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6fsosFSSxYZYmpLaXJ0cU1Pdjg/view?usp=sharing), script version and module *(roughly translated to English from French)*.

I successfully installed the module in `PSModulePath`   in:

```
[Environment]::GetFolderPath("mydocuments")\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
```

Command usage is very simple. You call it like that:

```
WinIsoInfo [[-Path] <String>] [<CommonParameters>]
```

Help is provided by module: `man WinIsoInfo`

### Usage Example:

```
WinIsoInfo -Path "E:\Win 10\Installation\ISO\Windows 10 x64 fr.iso"
```

The **ps1** script version is the exact same code as the **psm1** module but there are commands examples at the end of the file that you can un-comment and edit before running the script.

## Current Status

All the tests are and need to be run as admin, in console or **PowerShell ISE**.

The **ps1** script works as expected but the **psm1** module doesn't produce the same result.

At `line 108` of the code, there is a `Test-Path` in a `Switch` statement:

```
{(Test-Path "$wimPath\sources\install.wim") -or (Test-Path "$wimPath\sources\install.esd")}
```

In the **ps1** script, this `Test-Path` return `True` and user get the expected info.

But in the **psm1**, it seems to return `False` since `Switch` statement jump to the next test after this one. So at the end the user gets that the ISO doesn't contain windows setup. I can assure that the `Test-Path` should return `True` because I manually checked it while the function was paused by breakpoints.

## Hint and lead

There are 2 cases where I manage to get the module work as expected. But only using in **PowerShell ISE**, NOT in console.

### Using Automatic Variable `$?` in console pane while debugging module

#### Step to reproduce:

1. **PowerShell ISE** is not running.
2. Open **PowerShell ISE** as admin.
3. In console pane, run `import-module Get-WinIsoInfo -Force -Global -Verbose` or `import-module -path X:\Path\To\Modules\Get-WinIsoInfo -Force -Global -Verbose`
4. In console pane, run `WinIsoInfo -Path "X:\path\to\AnyWindowsSetup.iso"`
5. In my case, at this point, the command returns there is no Windows Setup in ISO file.
6. Now open the **Get-WinIsoInfo.psm1** and put a breakpoints anywhere between line 90-108.
7. do step 4 again
8. While the script is paused at breakpoints, run `$?` in the console pane then press **F10** then **F5**

And "voilà !" the module return the expected result and will keep working but only during **PowerShell ISE** session and inside **PowerShell ISE**. Command run in console still won't work. And the next time I run **PowerShell ISE**, the module won't find the setup image path again.

### Previously run the **ps1** script version in **PowerShell ISE**

#### Step to reproduce:

1. **PowerShell ISE** is not running.
2. Open **PowerShell ISE** as admin.
3. In console pane, run `import-module Get-WinIsoInfo -Force -Global -Verbose` or `import-module -path X:\Path\To\Modules\Get-WinIsoInfo -Force -Global -Verbose`
4. In console pane, run `WinIsoInfo -Path "X:\path\to\AnyWindowsSetup.iso"`
5. In my case, at this point, the command returns there is no Windows Setup in ISO file.
6. Now open the **Get-WinIsoInfo.ps1** script, edit a valid command at the end of the code then press **F5** to run it.
   *Note: Since the command in script has the same name as the module previously imported, at this point I don't know if the triggered function is the one from the **ps1** script or the one from the module. Tell me if you know.*
7. The script returns the expected result as Windows Setup info.
8. Close the **ps1** file (it is no longer needed in **PowerShell ISE** for the next to work)
9. do step 4 again

And "voilà !" the module return the expected result and will keep working but only during **PowerShell ISE** session and inside **PowerShell ISE**. Command run in console still won't work. And the next time I run **PowerShell ISE**, the module won't find the setup image path again.

## Conclusion

After the **Hint and lead** tests, I found out that they were some differences from modules imported in session before and after success. These key modules loaded by **PowerShell ISE** are `Storage` and `Microsoft.WSMan.Management`. I thought I found the solution and added this line to manifest:

```
RequiredModules = @("Storage";"Microsoft.PowerShell.Management";"Microsoft.PowerShell.Security";"Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility";"Microsoft.WSMan.Management")
```

I added all the modules that was present after the module works as expected, just to be sure.

I did the same for assemblies but 2 of them could not be imported: `Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.UserFilteredExceptionHandling` and `Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.resources`

Resulting in this new manifest line:

```
RequiredAssemblies = @("Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.Native";"Microsoft.WSMan.Runtime";"System.Security")
```

Unfortunately, it seems it is not enough to solve the issue.

Maybe other things has to be imported or it's a wrong lead.

I really hope you could reproduce the *bug* or at least I hope the **Hint and lead** section will lead you to find the cause and a solution. I'm too novice to understand why this happens on my system.

**My setup uses PowerShell v5.0 with Win 8.1 Pro.**

Comment: Just tested your module on Win 2012/PS 5 and it works fine. Also, breakpoints are working as usual in ISE for modules: you just `Import-Module -Path X:\Path\To\Get-WinIsoInfo`, open `Get-WinIsoInfo.psm1` in ISE and set breakpoints. I've checked them too.

Comment: I edited the question adding lots of details and tests results. @beatcracker Do you succeed to run the module in a **PS console** instead of **PowerShell ISE**? Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Just tried it, and it fails in **PS Console**. Quick debug session showed that while ISO is mounted, `Test-Path` on line `109` doesn't catch up with it and returns `false`. I've fixed this by adding `Get-PSDrive > $null` before the `Switch($wimPath)` statement.

Comment: Thank you @beatcracker. Although I've found a workaround that implies another approach, your solution is a relief. Tell me if I get it right: by calling `Get-PSDrive > $null` you force the host to load everything that is required so `Test-Path` on line 109 can properly work. Brilliant.

I will rewrite this module making it shorter and more elegant because it is currently a mess and doesn' t respect PoSH standard.

Comment: Yep, `Get-PSDrive` seems to force PS to update drive info for its providers. You can use it just after `Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath "$Path"`.

Comment: I'm experiencing a [similar issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39148473/4416750) with a PowerShell module not executing properly with the same exact code pasted from a script file that works fine...Did you find a resolution to this?

Comment: @Lews Therin
Yes but our issue is different. I had to change the code to get the same result. See [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3491ab7a-43b6-4200-9533-0e150626e1aa/module-returns-different-result-from-the-script-version-testpath?forum=winserverpowershell).