# PowerShell module terminating unexpectedly

Tags: powershell, powershell-module

A PowerShell module I'm working on is behaving very strangely...

I have the following code in a `RestoreTestFiles.psm1` file (located in `%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\RestoreTestFiles\`):

```
Function Restore-TestFiles([string]$backupDir, [string]$destinationDir, [bool]$overwrite)
{
    if (!(Test-Path $backupDir))
    { 
        Write-Host "Error, $backupDir does not exist."
        return
    }

    if ($backupDir.EndsWith("\*"))
    {
        Write-Host "$backupDir ends with \*!"
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "$backupDir does not end with \*."
    }

    if ($overwrite)
    {
        Copy-Item -Path $backupDir -Destination $destinationDir -Recurse -Force
    }
    else
    {
        Copy-Item -Path $backupDir -Destination $destinationDir -Recurse
    }

    Write-Host "Files sucessfully copied from $backupDir to $destinationDir."
}
```

And I call the function like this:

```
Import-Module RestoreTestFiles

Restore-TestFiles "C:\some\path\*" "C:\someOther\path\"
```

For some reason, the output is only either

> C:\some\path\* ends with \*!

or

> C:\some\path does not end with \*.

But it never runs the `Copy-Item` or the final `Write-Host`. If I set a breakpoint, the execution is all messed up:

> 1. Stops at breakpoint set on `if (!(Test-Path $backupDir))`
> 2. I step into and it goes to `if ($backupDir.EndsWith("\*"))`
> 3. I step into and it goes to `Write-Host "$backupDir ends with \*!"`
> 4. I step into and it stops running.

Why is the script terminating before it is supposed to?

**Edit**: I tried moving the function to a regular `.ps1` script and called the function from the same script and it works fine...it only terminates prematurely if the function is in a module and called from outside the module. What gives?

Comment: `$Overwrite` should be a `[Switch]` not a `[bool]`. Not sure if it will help this particular issue though

Comment: To begin debugging, run the following command line `$Error.Clear(); <your commands>; $Error`

Comment: @Eris Why should it be a `switch`? I can see that if a `switch` parameter is not supplied it will default to `$False` but why is `bool` wrong?

Comment: @Eris Running the `$Error.Clear()` fixed the script execution but I guess my question now is...why? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: switch vs bool: a `[Switch]` let's you just say `-Overwrite` without a value, and it evaluates to `$true`, a bool would evaluate to `$false`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by completely closing all open instances of the PowerShell ISE and re-opening my module.